# Ruby PATH Aptana Setup/Error Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, aptana, aptana3

Well, I'm slow...

I can't figure out how to change the PATH for Ruby in Aptana (plugin Eclipse).  The Apatana website doesn't offer any "how to".  And various searches have ended up no where.  Here's the error I'm getting.

```
/home/cmcintyre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)
     from /home/cmcintyre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
     from /home/cmcintyre/dev/bsro_rebrand_automation/test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Version: Aptana 3

OS: Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: You get the error when you attempt to RUN a ruby program? If so, you can change your run configuration to use a different environment, working directory, etc. under `Run > Run Configurations > Ruby Application`. Are you able to get this to run in the terminal? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdK-vG63wLM

Comment: Hi Sarah.  Thanks for the comment.  I can run a Ruby script from command line because it points to my root version of Ruby.  Aptana is pointing to the RVM install.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find that using RVM with Ubuntu 12.10 is not a good choice when working with Aptana.

I deleted the RVM directory and installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby.
```

I also re-installed Eclipse and added the Aptana plugin.  Installed Eclipse using apt-get, although this is probably not necessary.

Eclipse/Aptana found the appropriate Ruby directory.

When installing with Curl, Ruby is installed with the local user (although there are instructions for installing globally).  So when you use sudo commands to install gems it installs them to your root.  Aptana is getting confused, naturally, because you are not pointing to the right Ruby installation.

Worked perfectly.

I'm newer to Linux and assumed that it would be the same as on my Mac/PC.  This is definitely specific to Linux/Ubuntu though, because I used the same install procedure on my Mac with Curl and had no issues.

UPDATE:  As noted below you can also just update all your gems via RVM instead of using Rubygems.  This is probably a more appropriate response to the question.

Comment: Many Linux/Ubuntu veterans may know this (I am definitely a noob), but many applications I wanted to install were available using apt-get.  This is much preferable than trying other methods of installing.  I have also had zero issues thus far.